# MobileFirst 7.0 Consumer License

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have MobileFirst 7.0 Consumer Edition in our organization and hosting one app(Android and iOS) through it. We want to  build and deploy another App for our organization. My question is, do we need to buy another licensed server for our app or we can simply create another app inside the current MF Project without any extra licensing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following user documentation topics regarding licensing.

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/getstart/c_wl_editions.html
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/getstart/c_licensing.html?lang=en

For any further inquiries you should contact IBM directly - this is a programming Q&A website.